# Apache Camel Dynamic Consumers

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel

I have created this Camel routes

```
from("direct:pageExtraction")
            .bean(PageManager.class, "setProperties(*, ${headers})")
            .filter().method(PageManager.class, "exists").to("seda:pagePostProcessing").end()
            .to("seda:pageImposition");

            from("seda:pagePostProcessing")
            .bean(PageManager.class, "extractThumbnail(*, ${headers})")
            .bean(PageManager.class, "extractCMYKSeparation(*, ${headers})")
            .bean(PageManager.class, "persist(*, ${headers})")
            .bean(PageManager.class, "cleanUp(${headers})")
            .to("seda:pageImposition");

            from("seda:pageImposition")
            .bean(PageManager.class, "extractImposition(*, ${headers})")
            .to("seda:printQueue");
```

At the end, the seda:printQueue has no consumers, sending a message in a route like this apparently works fine. Now I want to introduce a new consumer **after** the routes have been initialized, I thought it would be possible to create a Spring bean programmatically and let Camel pick up the bean using the `@Consume(uri="seda:printQueue")` annotation, but as soon as I create the consumer Camel complains

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '4965d710-b5c7-41cf-97e9-a42bdfcea894' is defined]
```

Any thoughts?

**[UPDATE]**

I have traced back the error to the class where this new consumer is created, I'm instantiating the `PrintQueue` class and then integrating it to the Spring context using an `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` doing a `factory.autowireBean(printQueueInstance)` followed by `factory.initializeBean(printQueueInstance, id)` where `id` is the `4965d710-b5c7-41cf-97e9-a42bdfcea894` that appears in the exception above, so I think this has to be some kind of context scope problem, may be I am creating this bean in the main or web Spring context and it can't be access by the Camel context, is this possible?

Comment: How are you creating the `@Consume`-ing bean? Is it going into the registry? Is there any reason to create it at runtime rather than configure it in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Since this route is invoked synchronously via use of the "direct:" component, it does not appear to require "seda:" for asynchronous invocation of another bean.  In this situation, it would appear simplest to invoke a bean with Camel's bean methods for the Java DSL.  As an example shown in the Camel bean documentation at:

http://camel.apache.org/bean.html

I would simply do:

```
// Send message to the bean endpoint
// and invoke given method.
from("direct:start")
  // do other stuff in your route
   .beanRef("beanName", "methodName");
```